# Behaviour of priority inheritance in mixed systems

Tags: linux, synchronization, real-time

If I have a realtime linux system, but with certain subsystems not being realtime. What happens if I use priority inheritance with certain synchronization objects that are shared between both the realtime and the non-realtime part? The documentation seems to not really touch all that much on these crossover issues, though I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

After testing by constructing a priority inversion case and testing with variour configurations of real-time and non-realtime threads that hold the mutex that the high priority thread is waiting for, and testing with and without priority inversion turned on for the mutex in quest I can conclude that a non-realtime thread gets "elevated" to a realtime thread with the expected priority when a realtime thread is waiting for a mutex that it holds which has priority inheritance turned on for it. This was tested on the Linux 3.12 kernel.